# Annoying behavior for a ShapeDrawable in Android

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout, shapedrawable

I am using ShapeDrawable for LinearLayouts background. The Shapes are made by cod as I need to dynamically assign colors to them, depending on conditions. 
Here is my custom Shape

```
public class CustomShapeDrawable extends ShapeDrawable {
    private final Paint fillpaint, strokepaint, linePaint = new Paint();
    private int strokeWidth = 3;
    private final boolean disableBottomBorder;

    public CustomShapeDrawable(Shape s, int fill, int stroke, int strokewidth, boolean disablebottomborder) {
        super(s);
        fillpaint = new Paint(this.getPaint());
        fillpaint.setColor(fill);
        strokepaint = new Paint(fillpaint);
        strokepaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokepaint.setStrokeWidth(strokewidth);
        strokepaint.setColor(stroke);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokewidth + 1);
        linePaint.setColor(fill);
        strokeWidth = strokewidth;
        disableBottomBorder = disablebottomborder;

    }

    public CustomShapeDrawable(Shape s, int fill, int stroke, boolean disablebottomborder) {
        super(s);
        fillpaint = new Paint(this.getPaint());
        fillpaint.setColor(fill);
        strokepaint = new Paint(fillpaint);
        strokepaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokepaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        strokepaint.setColor(stroke);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth + 1);
        linePaint.setColor(fill);
        disableBottomBorder = disablebottomborder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Shape shape, Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        shape.resize(canvas.getClipBounds().right, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom);
        shape.draw(canvas, fillpaint);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getClipBounds().right, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom), new RectF(strokeWidth / 2, strokeWidth / 2, canvas.getClipBounds().right - strokeWidth / 2,
                canvas.getClipBounds().bottom - strokeWidth / 2), Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        canvas.concat(matrix);

        shape.draw(canvas, strokepaint);

        if (disableBottomBorder) {
            canvas.drawLine(0 + strokeWidth/2, shape.getHeight(), shape.getWidth() - strokeWidth/2, shape.getHeight(), linePaint);
        }
    }
```

This CustomShapeDrawable is used as StateListDrawable for my layouts like this:

```
        RoundRectShape shapeTopCorners = new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, null, null);
        ShapeDrawable shapeTopCornersNormal =
                new CustomShapeDrawable(shapeTopCorners, Global.getFleet().getSkins().getBackgroundcolour(), context.getResources().getColor(R.color.item_line), true);
        ShapeDrawable shapeTopCornersPressed =
                new CustomShapeDrawable(shapeTopCorners, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.menu_grey), context.getResources().getColor(R.color.item_line), true);

        StateListDrawable stateTopCornersRounded = new StateListDrawable();
        stateTopCornersRounded.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused }, shapeTopCornersPressed);
        stateTopCornersRounded.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, shapeTopCornersPressed);
        stateTopCornersRounded.addState(new int[] {}, shapeTopCornersNormal);
```

Everything looks ok, the layout has the same shape with the color I want. The ugly thing happens when on screen I get another element, like Keyboard or a AlertDialog. When my app gets focus again, the layouts go crazy with random lines and artifacts on them. 
Here is what I mean:

[image]

What can I do to prevent or fix this artifacts as they look ugly. I have no idea why this happens in the first place. Thank you for any help you may provide me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having any suggestions, the only thing that fixes things for now is:
- I made a method in my activities, called invalidate() in which for all layouts I wanted to refresh, i added layoutId.invalidate()
- whenever a alertdialog is shown, call invalidate()
- for all EditTexts onFocusChanged or onTextChanged, call invalidate()

Not quite an ergonomic solution but it seems to work for now.